# Unable to shim vendor js in webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

This task may seem straightforward, but I have been unable to figure it out.

Our site uses [flowplayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flowplayer), which is available via NPM.  However, our site uses the commercial version, which is only available via direct download.  Now that we're rebuilding the site in React, I want to bundle the commercial version using WebPack, but I keep running into problems.

Simply importing into a component via

`import flowplayer from '../vendor/flowplayer.js';`

yields several errors:

`Line 7:     'handler' is not defined      no-undef
Line 7:     'handler' is not defined      no-undef
Line 7:     'handler' is not defined      no-undef
Line 7:     'handler' is not defined      no-undef
Line 7:     Unexpected use of 'top'       no-restricted-globals
Line 8:     Unexpected use of 'self'      no-restricted-globals
Line 8:     Unexpected use of 'self'      no-restricted-globals
Line 451:   Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals
Line 3619:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals
Line 3619:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals
Line 3619:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals
Line 4875:  Unexpected use of 'self'      no-restricted-globals
Line 4875:  Unexpected use of 'self'      no-restricted-globals`

Is there any reason why the module loads when in the `node_modules` directory, as opposed to separately?

Also, as this app was previously built using `create-react-app`, might there be some default restrictions I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these are linting errors. you should disable linting of your vendor files - which is by default, but since you've put this outside of your node_modules, you need to also add your vendor folder to ignored.

you can `npm run eject` and edit your `webpack.config.dev` / `prod.js` files and add `ignore` on the plugin after the `test` or you can edit the file and make it ignored, eg like this:

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments

`/* eslint-disable */` at the top of the flowplayer file. of course, you can just fix their errors...